# How would you design a neural network that generates the positions of comparators in a sorting network given a set of numbers?

Tags: neural-networks, network-design

How would you design a neural network that generates the positions of comparators in a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) given a set of numbers?

I've tried to modify some already implemented networks that given a set of numbers it sorts the number. My goal is, given an unsorted sequence of numbers, to generate a sorting network that will sort those numbers. I am not asking for the complete solution, just a starting point.

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/mayank26saxena/deepsort